# Generating function for the number of partitions of [n] without singletons.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, bell-numbers

I know the generating function for the total number of partitions of [n] is 
given by $$ B(x)=e^{e^x-1}$$ I am struggling to find $V(X)$, the exponential generating function for the number of partitions containing no singleton blocks. I have read the answer is $V(x)=e^{e^x-x-1}$ but not sure how this is obtained.

Comment: I don't know the reference offhand, but it may be helpful to know that the result you're asking about is a special case of a very general formula. Suppose $A$ is a set of nonnegative integers, $B$ a set of positive integers, and $c_n$ is the number of partitions of $[n]$ such that the number of blocks is in $A$ and the size of each block is in $B$. The exponential generating function for $c_n$ is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{c_n}{n!}x^n=e_A(e_B(x))$$ where $$e_A(x)=\sum_{n\in A}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ and $$e_B(x)=\sum_{n\in B}\frac{x^n}{n!}.$$

Comment: The proof of the general formula in my first comment is probably a straightforward generalization of the way you prove that the egf of the Bell numbers is $e^{e^x-1}$ but I don't remember offhand how the proof for the Bell numbers goes.

Comment: This is absolutely the right place for your question. In my mental fog I thought for a few minutes that we were in a different place.

Comment: Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to put some structure $\mathcal{A}$ on a nonempty set (so $a_0=0$), and let $A(x)$ be the egf for $a_n$. Then $e^{A(x)}$ is the egf for partitioning $[n]$ into blocks and imposing structure $\mathcal{A}$ on each block. You can apply this to find the egf for the Bell numbers, where the structure $\mathcal{A}$ is just being a nonempty set, so $a_0=0$ and $a_i=1$ for $i>0$. Then if you want to impose the structure $\mathcal{B}$ of being a nonempty, non-singleton set, you want $b_0=b_1=0$ and $b_i=1$ for $i>1$. Now you just need to verify that what I said is true.

Answer (score 1):

We consider $[n]=\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ as combinatorial class $\mathrm{SET}_{n}(\mathcal{X})$ of  $n$ labelled objects. In terms of exponential  generating function (EGF) this is represented as
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{SET}_{n}(\mathcal{X})\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad\frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align*}
Allowing $n\geq 1$ gives a disjoint union of sets of objects and a series representation as EGF.
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{SET}_{n\geq 1}(\mathcal{X})=\bigcup_{n\geq  1}\mathrm{SET}_{n}(\mathcal{X})\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{x}-1
\end{align*}
We want to exclude singletons, so $n\geq 2$
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{SET}_{n\geq 2}(\mathcal{X})=\bigcup_{n\geq  2}\mathrm{SET}_{n}(\mathcal{X})\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=e^{x}-1-x\tag{1}
\end{align*}

We can use sets as building blocks in order to obtain more complex structures.  A set of $n$ objects of a combinatorial class $\mathcal{B}$ and disjoint unions of them are then  given as
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{SET}_{n}(\mathcal{B})\qquad&\Longrightarrow\qquad\frac{\left(B(x)\right)^n}{n!}\\
\mathrm{SET}_{n\geq 0}(\mathcal{B})=\bigcup_{n\geq  0}\mathrm{SET}_{n}(\mathcal{B})\qquad&\Longrightarrow\qquad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(B(x)\right)^n}{n!}=e^{B(x)}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
In (1) we also allow a neutral object $\epsilon$ with size $0$ and having no labels at all, represented as $1$ in terms of EGF.

We are now prepared for the current problem:

> The number of set-partitions of $[n]$ which do not contain singletons, is a set of sets each having at least two elements. Taking also the empty set-partition into account we consider according to (1) and (2) the combinatorial class
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{SET}_{n\geq 0}\left(\mathrm{SET}_{n\geq 2}(\mathcal{X})\right)
> \qquad\Longrightarrow}\qquad\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(e^x-1-x\right)^n}{n!}\color{blue}{=e^{e^x-1-x}}
> \end{align*}

*Hint:* A great presentation of this approach is given in section II.1 and II.2 of *[Analytic Combinatorics](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/book.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick.